# Can't install node.js and node-sass on my macOS Catalina

Tags: node.js, macos, sass, atom-editor

I've downloaded node js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and execute this command via terminal: sudo npm install -g node-sass. when i press enter, it elaborates but showing multiple errors and warning (see attached screenshot). Someone can help me? I'm getting crazy!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Babo.png)